# Unable to set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to any value

Tags: .net, security, ssl, exception

I have an existing .NET console application targeting 4.6.1. I have added the following method to update network security to tls1.2.

When running i am getting an ArgumentNullException - "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value"

Any ideas?

```
private static void Initialise()
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
```